# How do I extend automatic log out time to 60 minutes for sitecore users in CMS?

Tags: cms-only

Currently, in CMS the users are getting logged out after 10 minutes. How do I extend the automatic logout time for CMS users? In config, the `Authentication.ClientSessionTimeout` value is set to 60.

Comment: And what is in web.config in timeout in `<authentication …><forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="????????" />` on CM server?

Comment: @Marek Musielak looks like we didn't give any timeout value for this

Comment: Try to set those 2 to 60 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812994/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-sessionstate-timeout

Comment: @Marek Musielak Yes. It did. Thank you so much